# C Library Function Actual Implementation

Tags: c, glibc

I was wondering where I can find the actual C implementation of atoi() (or other such functions). I looked into stdlib.h but it seems like atoi is not implemented there. Is there a way to view the libc source tree and see the actual C code?

Comment: Question received a close vote for being off-topic, since whoever cast the vote assumes it's general programming question. I personally would argue that this is still relevant to Ubuntu. `glibc` is essential part of the Ubuntu as operating system, and knowing how certain functions are implemented is essential for developers and learners, and it's partially related to obtaining source code of programs that are standard to Ubuntu.  I'd caution against hasty close-voting.

Comment: @muru yeah, I'd say it's a good fit.  Exactly about getting the source code

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yes, and even for *nonessential* things, asking how to view the source code that is built to produce an Ubuntu package is hardly a general programming question either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtaining `glibc` code can be done via `apt-get` command. Here's basic process done in terminal, which takes no longer than 5 mins:

1. Create `glibc-source` directory with `mkdir glibc-source` and `cd glibc-source`
2. run `apt-get source glibc`
3. Once `apt-get` is done, you'll have 3 files and one directory, `glibc-2.23/`, `glibc_2.23-0ubuntu3.dsc`, `glibc_2.23-0ubuntu3.debian.tar.xz`,  `glibc_2.23.orig.tar.xz`. The file you want is `glibc-2.23/stdlib/atoi.c`

Answer (score 1):

Actually found it in the git repo here: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=atoi&type= 
Leaving this here to help anyone else who might wonder this in the future.